# Minimum requirement users must have to run a simple WPF browser application?

Tags: wpf

I am thinking of making a website using a WPF browser application, but would like to know the minimum requirement a client/internet user must have to access this website made by using WPF.

- Please state even the very basic requirements, like does he need to run Windows or will even Mac and Linux do, with any browser to view the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three main requirements:

- User has to run the application under Windows;
- The browser should be either Interned Explorer or Firefox;
- The .Net Framework should be installed on user's machine.

Answer (score 3):

One requirement is to have the `.NET framework` installed (same version as you used to build your application), so that means it will only run under Windows.

Also I think only Internet Explorer and Firefox support `XBAP` applications.

Also I assume that you know there is a lot of restrictions for you, the developer, on what is allowed or not compared to a full trust program. For example, the file system and registry among other things are restricted in a WPF browser application.